# Caching in Grails - what is cached by default and what can be enabled?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm curious about the support for database/GORM object caching provided by the Grails framework.

- What database caching is enabled by default?
- What database caching is provided by the framework but is disabled by default?
- What kind of database caching do you usually enable/disable in your Grails projects? Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grails uses Hibernate for GORM, so the database caching features are actually provided by Hibernate.

1. The Hibernate first level cache is enabled (which only lasts approximately the time of a user request). It can not be disabled.
2. The Hibernate second level cache is also enabled, but can be turned off by configuration. This cache will hold data for a long time (configurable by object type) unless something invalidates the data (an update)

For heavy-read applications, second-level cache should be enabled, you will save a lot of trips to your database, and it is 100% transparent to your application (almost no cost).

Regards,

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

3) We disabled disk cache overflow. Had to explicitly create `ehcache.xml` for that, from `ehcache-core-1.7.1.jar/ehcache-failsafe.xml`.

Disk cache overflow only made problems for us due to being slow and IO error prone.

Comment: Interesting. What settings did you set in your ehcache.xml? And where did you put it?

Comment: Set `diskPersistent="false"` and `overflowToDisk="false"`. Put it into `grails-app/config`. Tweaked `timeToIdleSeconds` and `timeToLiveSeconds`.